# are there any issues with attaching a property or function to a function object

Tags: javascript, function

While it is perfectly possible to attach a property or object to a function object, I was wondering if there are any issues with it that are not so obvious? I can't seem to find anything concrete online that talks about this.

```
var f = function(){};
f.blah = function(){};
```

Comment: A function object is just as much an object as anything else. The runtime does it a lot; think of all the functions on the Object constructor. So, no.

Comment: I do that all the time and have never had .... oh my god, my website's on fire ... kidding, never had an issue

Comment: The jQuery main entry point `$` has lots and lots of functions as properties.

Comment: You can read Javascript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. That book has everything you need to know about all the specialties of Javascript. Some features that might confuse you if you come from Java or C/C++. This is a talk about function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM, also by him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching properties to functions is central to Javascript's emulation of Object-Oriented Programming.

A Class is represented by a function object, and the properties attached to the function object dictate the methods and members and inheritance.

For example:

```
Class Animal:
    def moves:
        print("moves")
    def calls:
        print("calls")

Class Bird < Animal:
    def moves:
        print("flies")

Class Ostrich < Bird:
    def moves:
        print("runs")
    def calls:
        print("HONK")
```

Would be represented like this in Javascript:

```
var Animal = function() { console.log("Animal constructor"); }
Animal.prototype.moves = function() { console.log("moves"); }
Animal.prototype.calls = function() { console.log("calls"); }

var Bird = function() { Animal.call(this); console.log("Bird constructor"); }
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Bird.prototype.moves = function() { console.log("flies"); }

var Ostrich = function() { Bird.call(this); console.log("Ostrich constructor"); }
Ostrich.prototype = Object.create(Bird.prototype);
Ostrich.prototype.moves = function() { console.log("runs"); }
Ostrich.prototype.calls = function() { console.log("HONK"); }
```

For more information, check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: *"Javascript's emulation of Object-Oriented Programming"* - JavaScript doesn't *emulate* object-oriented programming, it supports it directly. It just doesn't do classical inheritence, but that is *not* essential to OO (despite what some Java programmers like to claim). Anyway, the example code you show doesn't seem to attach properties to functions, it attaches them to the `.prototype` objects (which aren't functions here).

Comment: Hmmmm. Inheritance in Java: `class Bird extends Animal`. Inheritance in JavaScript: `var Bird = function() { Animal.call(this); }; Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // NOT new Animal() per MDN` I'm sorry, but the JavaScript "inheritance" procedure strikes me as not being as direct or straightforward. That's why there were so many class emulation libraries before ES2015. As for .prototype, point taken, but I think the example is still useful to show that functions are far more flexible in JavaScript than at first appears, and that's valuable. Cheers!